# File system content different on device and on desktop

Tags: usb, file-system, file-transfer, file-management, nexus-9

I've got a Nexus 9 which I'm using to read PDF graphic novels.

My process for getting the files onto the device is to connect it to my PC via USB and drag the files into the `Download` folder on the device. From here I'm then able to manipulate the files as I see fit, such as importing them into Mantano Reader, a side effect of which is that the files get moved from Download into `Mantano/books`.

This is fine and good, with both Mantano and ES File Explorer on the device reporting that the files are in `Mantano/books`. But if explore the drive via USB on my PC, it shows that the files are still in `Download`. This isn't limited to a single PC either, as I've taken a look using Windows, OS X and Ubuntu.

The only thing I can imagine is that the location of the files has somehow cached, with the wrong location being reported via USB.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Comment: Couldn't it rather be the files were *copied* to the Mantano directory (instead of being moved)? Have you checked that with ES?

Comment: No, I've looked in the Mantano folder, and the files aren't there. Futher to this, if you try doing anything with the files in the Download folder, such as copy them to the computer, it complains that it can't get the files. This is further making me think the file system is caching the table of contents, rather than reporting the files accurately.

Comment: Wait a second: In your question you write "This is fine and good, with both Mantano and ES File Explorer on the device reporting that the files are in `Mantano/books`" – but now you write "I've looked in the Mantano folder, and the files aren't there." So, to be or not to be (there)? With what have you checked this time? To get a clear idea, we need some consistency here :)

Comment: Long story short, when viewing the files via the device itself, they're where they're meant to be. When viewing the files via USB on my PC, they're not. This is what I was trying to clarify with my previous comment, something I obviously failed to do so.

Comment: OK, so if I got it right: The files are in the Montano folder, no longer in Downloads – but only the computer thinks different? Then that might be rather an OS question (implementation). What's the OS on the computer, and what are you using to check (e.g. "Windows 7", "Explorer via MTP")?

Comment: I've tried using Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu (using whatever the default is once you've plugged in via USB) and OS X (using the Android File Transfer app). All three of them report the same information.

Comment: That should be MTP then. Does a forced refresh of the folder in whatever file explorer you're using on the computer do any good then?

Comment: Also tried that,no joy.

Comment: OK, then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: It is an unusual one, that's for sure. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If you reboot the Nexus device and then plug it in and browse on the PC do they still show up there? The Media Manager in android may be the one that handles telling MTP what files are in what folders. Rebooting should cause Media Manager to reindex the folders. If after reboot they are not there, then Android is caching the files via Media Manager.